# Angular Formly repeat section - Async model. Not working

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I'm trying to create a custom repeat type for formly (for file uploads) that takes in a certain number of fields received from the server. I'm not sure I'm being clear but overall the "configuration" of the number of file fields to display to the user comes from a server: Hence async.

I've configured everything with a mock-data file just using of() in my service to sort of simulate an Observable that I would get from an http call but without using delays. Everything worked great and displayed but when I connected the whole thing to my real dev. back-end no field displayed.

Here's a reproduction of the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-46hgss?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I have no idea why it's doing that or how to find a solution for this. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!